# CSS not responsive to certain range

Tags: html, css, web, responsive-design

newbie here, but I actually did go through many forums here but can't seems to find the solution.

I'm trying to make three  and responsive to 3 different dimensions of screens. The smaller one **(col-md)** and the bigger one **(col-lg)** works but not the middle one **(col-md)**

I don't know what I missed out but the middle one not working, please let me know if there's any solution to it..
In html file,

```
<div class="style col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sd-12">
        <div class="boxtitle">
        Chicken
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>
            SOME TEXT HERE</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="style col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sd-12">
        <div class="boxtitle">
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>
            SOME TEXT HERE
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="style col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sd-12">

        <div class="boxtitle">
        Sushi
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>
                SOME TEXT HERE
        </p>
    </div>
<div>
```

In CSS file,

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .col-sd-12 {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
  }
}


@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    .col-md-6, .col-md-12 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-md-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-md-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .col-lg-4 {
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
  } 
}
```

Comment: I have made an edit to my answer so kindly check it!!!

Comment: your problem lies with <div class="boxtitle> which is not closed yet in your code

Comment: Sir kindly check it now for the results. You will better understand it now with the help of background-color and minimize browser window for results

Comment: remove the border, as it won't let it happen because width will then be border+50% and border+50% which will take two lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code sample there are som syntax errors: unclosed .boxtitle in second block and unclosed last .style block. If these errors are fixed, the code works correctly and there are no problems

Answer (score 1):

```css
.style:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #bbb;
}

.style:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #666;
}

.style:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #999;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .col-sd-12 {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
  }
}


@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    .col-md-6, .col-md-12 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-md-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-md-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .col-lg-4 {
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
  } 
}
```

```html
<div class="style col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sd-12">
   <div class="boxtitle">
      Chicken
   </div>
   <div>
      <p>
         SOME TEXT HERE
      </p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="style col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sd-12">
   <div class="boxtitle">
     Pizza
   </div>
   <div>
      <p>
         SOME TEXT HERE
       </p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="style col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sd-12">

  <div class="boxtitle">
     Sushi 
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>
       SOME TEXT HERE
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Kindly close your last `<div class="style col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sd-12">` also.

Your biggest fault is that you haven't closed `div class="boxtitle` in second div which is creating all the problem

Comment: Kindly accept my answer if you feels that I have solved your query...

Comment: Hello sir, thanks for your time helping.I did copy paste the nsippet but it does not work as well. same as before.

Comment: Check my snippet now

Comment: Nope, no difference. The previous unclosed <div> tag is just mistake, I apologize for that. Thanks for the code, but the two <div> still not going into 50% 50%

https://ibb.co/yPChdw7

Comment: border is preventing them from doing so, you can remove the border and then check the results

Comment: Hello sir, tried removing border but no changes. But removing margin does achieve the results i want. However, If I don't put margin(i only use 1px though), the boxes seems a lil squizzy.

Comment: use padding for it either

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216370/discussion-between-om-chaudhary-and-nelson-wong).

Answer (score 0):

You typed `col-sd-12`, I think you meant `col-sm-12`?

Comment: col-sd-12 is correct, but the problem lies somewhere else which is solved below...